# proverbs and first conditional

Tags: conditionals

From what I know, if we are talking about a rule, zero conditional should be used. Therefore, proverbs using "if" should use zero conditional (http://www.1-language.com/englishcoursenew/unit40_grammar_exs.htm).

However, I've come across some proverbs that use the first conditional:

> Choose a job you love, and you will never have to work a day in your life.

> If you play with fire, you’ll get burned.

Any idea why?

Comment: Why choose any word or phrase over another? Both sentences in the question are grammatical, understandable, and normal.

Answer (score 2):

Your linked article contains this statement:

> "The zero conditional (using If you can't...) is **often** found in old sayings and proverbs."

This is true, it *often* is, but that doesn't mean it *always* is. Proverbs are defined as "stating a general truth or piece of advice". Advice isn't the same as an inescapable fact, which a zero conditional statement usually conveys, so don't expect all proverbs to follow that format.

Regarding your specific example - although conditional statements tend to use "if" or "when", there are lots of other ways of phrasing such a statement either omitting or replacing "if". For example:

- Choose a job you love, **and** you will never have to work a day in your life.
- **If you** choose a job you love, you will never have to work a day in your life.
- **When you** choose a job you love, you will never have to work a day in your life.
- **As long as you** choose a job you love, you will never have to work a day in your life.
- **Provided that you** choose a job you love, you will never have to work a day in your life.

These all mean the same thing - that if condition [x] is true, *it follows that* [y] is true.

Comment: Also, "zero conditional" uses simple present tense. All of those use future tense for the consequent.